# Need help to produce output for below input using python list

Tags: python, python-2.7

Input data as below:

0:  70     1:  60     2:  66     3:  62     4:  72     5:  82
 6:  83     7:  86     8:  95     9:  96    10:  98    11:  98
12:  96    13:  94    14:  66    15:  62    16:  60    17:  66
18:  67    19:  67    20:  64    21:  66    22:  66    23:  69

Output as below using python

[image]

or

0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   10  11  12  13  14  15  16  17  18  19  20  21  22  23

70  60  66  62  72  82  83  86  95  96  98  98  96  94  66  62  60  66  67  67  64  66  66  69

Comment: Is the input a string?

Comment: What are you actually asking?

Comment: Hi, welcome to stack overflow. Providing a https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve may increase your chance to get a satisfactory answer.

Comment: Looks like input is a dictionary!

Comment: yes.. it is a string.. but we need convert integer if possible.. put in table which mentioned in output

Comment: What have you tried? Please show the code you tried for solving the problem. SO users are not meant for code writing services.

Comment: Give me 4 minutes and I'll solve it for you.

Comment: If input is `dict` like `a = {0: 1, 1: 2}` something like that, Then you can get keys using `a.keys()` and values using `a.values()`

Comment: How about we stop guessing and just close the question until OP comes up with a [MCVE] and an attempt?

Comment: I need it in HTML table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Code (updated):

```
import re

l = "0: 70 1: 60 2: 66 3: 62 4: 72 5: 82 6: 83 7: 86 8: 95 9: 96 10: 98 11: 98 12: 96 13: 94 14: 66 15: 62 16: 60 17: 66 18: 67 19: 67 20: 64 21: 66 22: 66 23: 69"

l = re.split("\s(?=\d+:)", l)

a = []
b = []
for x in l:
    a.append(x.split(": ")[0])
    b.append(x.split(": ")[1])

a = ["<td>" + x + "</td>" for x in a]
b = ["<td>" + x + "</td>" for x in b]

print("<table><tr>" + "".join(a) + "</tr><tr>" + "".join(b) + "</tr></table>")
```

Comment: am getting an error as below


Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".\SRX-Util-report.py", line 123, in <module>
    b.append(x.split(": ")[1])
IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: @GirishB Code updated.

Comment: Great Thanks for your help... its working for me –

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming your input data structure is python `dict` (Associative array). And you are trying to print list of keys and values inside this `dict`. Below code snippet will print `keys` and `values`

```
input = {0: 70, 1: 60, 2: 66, 3: 62, 4: 72, 5: 82, 6: 83, 7: 86, 8: 95, 9: 96, 10: 98, 11: 98, 12: 96, 13: 94, 14: 66, 15: 62, 16: 60, 17: 66, 18: 67, 19: 67, 20: 64, 21: 66, 22: 66, 23: 69}
# Below is the output with keys, values
print(input.keys())
print(input.values())
```

Comment: I need it in HTML table

Comment: Python dicts (especially Py2.7) DO NOT keep order! You might have been misdirected since you are using some version of Py3.x that probably does remember order of insertion, but it has not always been true!